# Is it acceptable to combine and then split two air ducts?

Tags: installation

I have a small older house that had wall stack ductwork running from the basement to the upper level at two different points.  I have installed a beam in place of the wall and will be combining the two ducts into one and then branching/splitting it/them back to their original venting locations in the rooms/ hall.  I realize that math/volume considerations don't equal out, however, I'm not sure how essential this is as it's an older home with various flaws.  I'm writing to see if this is something that folks would consider a big time don't do it.... Before i do it... Thoughts?

Comment: So there used to be two ducts going up the wall, then you removed the wall. Now you want to use a single duct between the basement and the attic, right?  Do you plan on increasing the size of the single duct, or are you planning on using one of the existing ducts? A sketch of the previous and planned ducting might help.

Answer (score 1):

Combining 2, 3-1/4x12 ducts into one would require a  duct 8 x 8 or 9" round. If this isn't the answer you need let me know.